# Mapping in 60 files: "R1" and "R2" with a file called repeatfile.fas

Tags: bash, mapping

I have a group of 60 files like this:

```
Pk_sd_ s1_R1_001.gz
Pk_sd_ s1_R2_001.gz
Pk_sd_ s2_R1_001.gz
Pk_sd_ s2_R2_001.gz
Pk_sd_ s3_R1_001.gz
Pk_sd_ s3_R2_001.gz
………._s60_R-_001.gz
```

Moreover, i have the following script to map `R1` and `R2` using a file called `repeatfile.fas`:

```
bwa mem -t 8  repeatfile.fas Pk_sd_ s1_R1_001.gz  Pk_sd_ s1_R2_001.gz | samtools view -Su | samtools sort -o mapped_to_repeat.bam
```

Does somebody know how to use this script once for all 60 files in a loop using bash?

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in {1..60}; do
    bwa mem -t 8  repeatfile.fas Pk_sd_ "s${i}_R1_001.gz"  Pk_sd_ "s${i}_R2_001.gz" | samtools view -Su | samtools sort -o mapped_to_repeat.bam
done
```

Comment: Almost nailed it... the number that changes is the one after the `s`, not the `001` at the end. Try `for i in {0..60}` and substitute like `"Pk_sd_ s${i}_R1_001.gz"`